# private static method in class pros and cons?

Tags: java, static, private

Sometimes when writing a class you'll need some helper methods that take care of some simple stuff (change a string in a certain way or do some simple calculations).

If helper functionalities are small enough (and not needed by any other class) it makes sense to write a helper method in this class.

Now: assuming you'll need no access to any member variables, would it be better do make this method `private` or `private static`

the following example: just implements a method that checks if a string is not `null` and contains foo.

```
public class SomeClass

...

 public void calculate(String inputString) {
  ...
  boolean foo = getFoo(inputString);
 }

 private (static) boolean getFoo(String inputString) {
  return inputString != null && inputString.contains("foo");
 }

}
```

Are there pros and cons in making the method static or non-static. Is there a general do and don't?

Comment: "Side effects" is generally used to mean something else in a programming context.  I've changed your question terminology slightly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would personally make the method static - it makes it clearer that it *doesn't* depend on the state of the object. That can have knock-on effects in terms of thread safety (although if it were to access *static* members of the type, you'd need to be careful of that).

Given that it's private, you don't need to worry about whether or not subclasses would want to override it.

You can always make it non-static later - I *think* the only side-effect of that would be to potentially change the serialization ID. (Binary serialization is a pain like that.)

Comment: serialisation ID is changed when it's static or non-static?

Comment: @leifg: Yes, I believe that switching between the two will change the ID. Try it if you're concerned about it.

Comment: @Jon Surely if you override serialVersionUID in your class then that isn't an issue?

Comment: @Bringer128: Yes, absolutely. I was just thinking of side-effects which *could* bite you.

Answer (score 2):

Make it non-static if it needs access to non-static member variables, and make it static if it doesn't.

Comment: I actually disagree with that. A mix is never a good choice for code-style and readability. Since you may have other helper functions using non-static members i think its better to declare helper functions continuously as non-static in order to get a homogeneous code-style. It even doesnt force you to make single functions non-static (after you declared thm static some time before) for threadsafety-purpose.

Comment: @Paranaix: A mix of static and non-static functions in a class seems perfectly reasonable to me.  Even if it was a good idea to avoid such a mix, I would probably be making all of my helper functions static and would pass in the object as an argument.  Having a non-static method that makes no use of object state is confusing.